# Question on uncertainity

Tags: microeconomics, uncertainty, mechanism-design, principal-agent, adverse-selection

> Please imagine that Nicole is uncertain of her future wealth. Her wealth in the bad state of the world is zero. Her wealth in the good state is $w>0$.  Each state is initially equally likely. However nikole can purchase technology (such as safety equipment) that will make the good state more likely. If she buys $x>0$ units, the probability of the good state becomes $q(x)>1/2$ where $q(x)$is strictly increasing and strictly concave in x, with $q(x)<1$ for all x. *To purchase x units, Nichole commits to pay $t(x)<w$ if the good state materialized. She doesn’t pay anything in the bad state* Nicole is risk natural. Andrew faces the exact same problem however Andrew is risk averse. Normalize andrew’s utility in the bad state to $u(0)=0$. Assume that $q(x) $ and $t(x)$ are such that both Nichole and Andrew would like to buy a strictly positive quantity f the technology.
>
> So thinking of x as a choice variable formulate Nicole ‘s and Andrew ‘s maximization problem. How can I prove who buys the larger quantity of the technology? And what does this result tells to me intuitively? And secondly how can I prove how the optimal quantity for ether agents depends on $w$?
>
> In the second case, I assume that the technology is provided by a risk national firm whose costs of supplying x units of the technology is $kx$ where $k>0$. The firm knows Nichole ‘s and Andrew ‘s preferences and is allowed to make different offers to them. If we imagine that the firm decides to offer Nichole a fixed quantity of $x_N>0$ and Andrew a fixed quantity of $x_A>0$. Let  $t_N(x_N)$  and  $t_A(x_A)$ denote the optimal price to charge Nichole and Andrew respectively (where I should remember this is allocated only in the good state).
>
> Given a fixed $x_N$ , I need to derive  $t_N(x_N)$and the implicit expression of  $t_A(x_A)$ for a fixed $x_A$. If $x_N=x_A$, can I say that  $t_N(x_N)$  is greater than  $t_A(x_A)$? Or not?  I want to prove it and what can I say about this intuitively? And I want to derive  $t_N’(x_N)$ and  $t_A’(x_A)$. Finally how can I derive an implicit characterization of the optimal quantity to offer to Nichole $x_N$. And how can prove whether the optimal value of $x_A$ is greater than the optimal value of $x_N$ or not?

---

What is only done as a solution is

For Nichole

$$\max_{x} \ \ q(x) u(w-xt(x))+(1-q(x))u(0)$$

FOCs

$$q’(x) u(w-xt(x))+q(x) u’(w-xt(x))-(w-xt(x))’+(1-q’(x))’u(0)=0$$

$$q’(x) u(w-xt(x))+q(x) (-t(x)-x)u’(w-xt(x))=u(0)q’(x)$$

$$q’(x) u(w-xt(x))-q’(x) u(0)=q( x )u’(w-xt(x))(t(x)+x)$$
$$q’(x)[ u(w-xt(x))- u(0)]=q( x )u’(w-xt(x))(t(x)+x)$$
$$q’(x)[(1/q(x))[u(q(x)(w-xt(x)))- u(0)]]=q( x )u’(w-xt(x))(t(x)+x)$$

$$(q’(x)/q(x))[u(q(x)(w-xt(x)))- u(0)]=q( x )u’(w-xt(x))(t(x)+x)$$

Risk natural

$$q(x)(w-xt(x)+(1-q(x))u(0)=u(q(x)(w-xt(x))$$

$$[u(w-xt(x))-u(0)]=(1/q(x))[u(q(x)(w-xt(x))-u(0)]$$

Risk averse

$$q(x)u(w-xt(x))\le u(q(x)(w-xt(x))$$

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

---

The original version of question

[image]

---

**Edit: for adding my solution for remaining parts**

Take that Nichole is risk neutral. I end up.

$${\partial u \over \partial x}[q’(x)(w-t(x))-q(x)t’(x)]=0$$
$$q’(x)(w-5(x))-q(x)t’(x )=0$$ and differentiate this w.r.t. w.
$${\partial q’(x) \over \partial x}{\partial x \over \partial w}(w-t(x))+q’(x)[{\partial w \over \partial w}-{\partial t \over \partial x}{\partial x \over \partial w}-\frac{\partial q(x)}{\partial x}{\partial x \over \partial w}t’(x)-q(x){\partial t’(x) \over \partial x}{\partial x \over \partial w}=0$$

After calculations

$${\partial x \over \partial w}=+{q’(x)\over -q”( x)(w-t(x)+2q’(x)t’(x)+q(x)t”(x)}>0$$

---

*Another part’s solution:*

$$\text{profit}=t_N(x_N)k-Nx_N$$
Subject to $q(x)u(w-t_N(x_N))\ge 0$

But again for this part I couldn’t set up the equation.

What I thought is

$$max_{(t_N(x_N), t_A(x_A))} \ \ q(x_A)[t_A(x_A)-kx_A]+q(x_N)[t_N(x_N)-kx_N]$$

First order conditions

W.r.t. $(t_N(x_N)$

$$q’(x_N)(t_N(x_N)-kx_N)+q(x_N)[t’_N(x_N)-k]=0$$

$$t_N(x_N)={q’(x_N)kx_N-q(x_N)[t’_N(x_N)-k]\over q’(x_N)}$$

Similar for Andrew

$$t_A(x_A)={q’(x_A)kx_A-q(x_A)[t’_A(x_A)-k]\over q’(x_A)}$$

Comment: Question is incomplete. You haven't specified clearly what $t(x)$ is.

Comment: Sorry @Amit I missed this part. But I corrected it and also I posted the original version of the question. Really thank you for your reply.

Comment: Just to clarify- what exactly are you interested in for the first question? Are you looking for help interpreting the FOCs/RN/RA formulas you gave (and how to use them to see who buys more of the technology)? 

Also- on that note: I think you're missing some close-parentheses and close-brackets in those RN/RA formulas

Comment: @Andrew I tried to edit some wrong parenthesis. We try to the first part but could not proceed it. Can you want to help? Thanks

Comment: @Amit I updated my question. Whenever you find time, please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are given that $u$ is increasing and concave, and $u(0) = 0$. This implies that $\dfrac{u(t)}{t}$ is decreasing in $t$, and also, $\dfrac{u(t)}{t} >  u'(t)$ for all $t$.

Nicole's maximization problem :
\begin{eqnarray*} \max_{x} \  q(x)(w-t(x))\end{eqnarray*}

FOC :
$q'(x)(w-t(x)) = q(x)t'(x)$

Suppose $x_N$ solves Nicole's problem. Therefore, it satisfy

$q'(x_N)(w-t(x_N)) = q(x_N)t'(x_N)$
or equivalently,

$\dfrac{q'(x_N)}{q(x_N)t'(x_N)} = \dfrac{1}{w-t(x_N)} \tag{1}$

Andrew's maximization problem :
\begin{eqnarray*} \max_{x} \  q(x)u(w-t(x))\end{eqnarray*}

FOC :
$q'(x)u(w-t(x)) = q(x)t'(x)u'(w-t(x))$

or equivalently,

$\dfrac{q'(x)u(w-t(x))}{q(x)t'(x)} = u'(w-t(x)) \tag{2}$

Let us compare the two sides of the above FOC (2) at $x = x_N$,

LHS  = $\dfrac{q'(x_N)u(w-t(x_N))}{q(x_N)t'(x_N)} = \dfrac{u(w-t(x_N))}{w-t(x_N)} > u'(w-t(x_N)) =$ RHS

Since at $x = x_N$ LHS of (2) is greater than RHS of (2), we need to reduce the value of $x$ to make them equal. So, there is $x_A < x_N$ such that

$\dfrac{q'(x_A)u(w-t(x_A))}{q(x_A)t'(x_A)} = u'(w-t(x_A)) \tag{3}$

Therefore, Nicole buys larger quantity of technology.

Observing the FOCs, we can also conclude that increase in $w$ lead to increase in optimal quantity chosen by both.

Now try to solve the remaining two parts.

Comment: Amit your solution really helps me thank you. We have tried to solve. And I added this solution below of the question box. Please can you look at? What do think? True? And please help me to complete missing ones of this solution. Many thanks! :)